# how to wait until all background process completes and merge the result obtained form each of the background process

Tags: vb.net, background-process

In the below code i have created the background process dynamically, I have  Questions

> 1.) Is there any possible way to send the **val** as parameter to the WorkerDoWork ?
>
> 2.) How to check if all the background process were completed and merge all result-set obtained form the background process?

```
For Each val In clientdict.Values.Distinct
                ' deal with it. 
                NumWorkers = NumWorkers + 1
                'MessageBox.Show(NumWorkers.ToString)
                ReDim Workers(NumWorkers)
                Workers(NumWorkers) = New BackgroundWorker
                Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerReportsProgress = True
                Workers(NumWorkers).WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
                AddHandler Workers(NumWorkers).DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
                AddHandler Workers(NumWorkers).RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
                Workers(NumWorkers).RunWorkerAsync()
                
            Next

    Private Sub WorkerDoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

    End Sub
    Private Sub WorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' I'm done!
    End Sub
```

Comment: You really ought not to be using `BackgroundWorkers` like that. You'd be better off using one `BackgroundWorker` and creating multiple `Task(Of T)` objects in its `DoWork` event handler.  You can then call `Task.WhenAll` to wait until they are all done and each `Task(Of T)` has a `Result` property of type `T` that you can get and combine for a final result.

Comment: If you were going to stick with `BackgroundWorkers`, you can pass an argument to `RunWorkerAsync` and get that back in the `DoWork` event handler via `e.Argument`. That's explained in the documentation for the `BackgroundWorker` class so you should already know because you should have read that documentation before posting here.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me the RunWorkerAsync it works but i need to stick with BackgroundWorkers , so is there any way  merge all result-set obtained form the background process ?

Comment: You could set a field to the number of `BGWs` you create and then in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler you would decrement that field and check whether it was zero. If it was, you know that you're the last one to finish and you can combine the results and use the data.  Obviously you would have to put each result somewhere in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler too, e.g. a `List(Of T)` or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Can you give me a brief details for the below line  " Obviously you would have to put each result somewhere in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler too, e.g. a List(Of T) or whatever is appropriate"

Comment: I don't know what the result of each of your background tasks is so I can't be too specific. You can pass an object of any type you like from `DoWork` to `RunWorkerCompleted` via the `e.Result` property. If, for instance, the result is a `String`, you would assign a `List(Of String)` to a field and add each result to that. When you worker count gets to zero, you can then process that complete `List(Of String)` in whatever way is appropriate, e.g. concatenate them all into one multiline `String`.